# TPL Queue Processing

Tags: c#, queue, task-parallel-library

I'm currently working on a a project and I have a need to queue some jobs for processing, here's the requirement:

1. Jobs must be processed one at a time
2. A queued item must be able to be waited on

So I want something akin to:

```
Task<result> QueueJob(params here)
{
   /// Queue the job and somehow return a waitable task that will wait until the queued job has been executed and return the result.
}
```

I've tried having a background running task that just pulls items off a queue and processes the job, but the difficulty is getting from a background task to the method.

If need be I could go the route of just requesting a completion callback in the QueueJob method, but it'd be great if I could get a transparent Task back that allows you to wait on the job to be processed (even if there are jobs before it in the queue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Func<T>` takes no parameters and returns a value of type T. The jobs are run one by one and you can wait on the returned task to get the result.

```
public class TaskQueue
{
    private Queue<Task> InnerTaskQueue;

    private bool IsJobRunning;

    public void Start()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (InnerTaskQueue.Count > 0 && !IsJobRunning)
                {
                     var task = InnerTaskQueue.Dequeue()
                     task.Start();
                     IsJobRunning = true;
                     task.ContinueWith(t => IsJobRunning = false);
                }
                else
                {
                     Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Task<T> QueueJob(Func<T> job)
    {
        var task = new Task<T>(() => job());
        InnerTaskQueue.Enqueue(task);
        return task;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this didn't solve my particular problem entirely, it's a great skeleton for what I did and solves the problem in a good generic fashion, so I'm going to mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: The question says that “Jobs must be processed one at a time”. This code fails that requirement completely.

Comment: Also, this code is not thread-safe, you can't access `Queue` from multiple threads without locking. And busy waiting is a bad idea, even if you add `Thread.Sleep()`.

Comment: The requirement that tasks run 'one at a time' means that you do not need multiple threads accessing the queue at the same time. A single thread with a while loop dequeing items one at a time is thread safe. As far as waiting for a job to finish before the next started that is as simple as setting a boolean property true/false when it is starts and finishes.

Comment: As far as the sleep, this is a single thread on the thread pool so we are not suspending a whole thread, the thread pool is smart enough to make optimizations and schedule appropriately. At this point it just sounds like nit-picking...Stack Overflow is about giving guidence where people need help which in this case it sounds like I was able to point him in the right direction. Of course if performance is tight he will make optimizations where needed but none of that changes the actual solution of how to queue delegates, etc. which is what this question is about.

Comment: “A single thread with a while loop dequeing items one at a time is thread safe.” But a single thread dequeuing items and another thread enqueueing them isn't. (BTW, since you didn't [@-notify](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/130186) me, I didn't know you replied to me, that's why I'm replying this late.)

Comment: And if the waiting is that simple, why don't you add it to your code?

Comment: “so we are not suspending a whole thread” Except you are. If you block a thread waiting, that thread can't be used for anything else. The fact that it's a `ThreadPool` thread doesn't change anything about that. And I really do think that SO answers should promote good practices, not just something that works. (Although your code doesn't even do that.)

Comment: @svick I believe SO is effective because it allows programmers to share knowledge in the most clear and concise way. I don't think it's even mandatory to post working code because this site is not supposed to be a copy and paste style of "i need a function to do this". It's more of "I am having trouble approaching this problem". Then people can post suggestions and solutions that help the asker understand the problem better and hopefully develop their own solution. It's the difference between giving a man a fish and giving him a fishing pole.

Comment: A community flourishes when people collaborate together to help each other instead of trying to step on each others throats to show who's 'more right'. You have some good suggestions so thank you for your input and happy coding :)

Answer (score 6):

You might find [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx) useful, it can be used to create a `Task` that completes exactly when you want it to. If you combine it with `BlockingCollection<T>`, you will get your queue:

```
class JobProcessor<TInput, TOutput> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Func<TInput, TOutput> m_transform;

    // or a custom type instead of Tuple
    private readonly
        BlockingCollection<Tuple<TInput, TaskCompletionSource<TOutput>>>
        m_queue =
        new BlockingCollection<Tuple<TInput, TaskCompletionSource<TOutput>>>();

    public JobProcessor(Func<TInput, TOutput> transform)
    {
        m_transform = transform;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(ProcessQueue, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    private void ProcessQueue()
    {
        Tuple<TInput, TaskCompletionSource<TOutput>> tuple;
        while (m_queue.TryTake(out tuple, Timeout.Infinite))
        {
            var input = tuple.Item1;
            var tcs = tuple.Item2;

            try
            {
                tcs.SetResult(m_transform(input));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.SetException(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public Task<TOutput> QueueJob(TInput input)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TOutput>();
        m_queue.Add(Tuple.Create(input, tcs));
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        m_queue.CompleteAdding();
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvote for something I'd not seen before! This may prove useful, for now I've got a solution working.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for something like this:

```
class TaskProcessor<TResult>
{
    // TODO: Error handling!

    readonly BlockingCollection<Task<TResult>> blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<Task<TResult>>(new ConcurrentQueue<Task<TResult>>());

    public Task<TResult> AddTask(Func<TResult> work)
    {
        var task = new Task<TResult>(work);
        blockingCollection.Add(task);
        return task; // give the task back to the caller so they can wait on it
    }

    public void CompleteAddingTasks()
    {
        blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
    }

    public TaskProcessor()
    {
        ProcessQueue();
    }

    void ProcessQueue()
    {
        Task<TResult> task;
        while (blockingCollection.TryTake(out task))
        {
            task.Start();
            task.Wait(); // ensure this task finishes before we start a new one...
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on the type of app that is using it, you could switch out the BlockingCollection/ConcurrentQueue for something simpler (eg just a plain queue).  You can also adjust the signature of the "AddTask" method depending on what sort of methods/parameters you will be queueing up...

Comment: A more efficient way would be use `task.RunSynchronously()`.

Comment: Also, your code won't work, because this overload of `TryTake()` returns `false` immediately if the collection is empty. You need to use an overload that allows you to specify a timeout and set that to infinity.

Comment: One more thing: you're starting `ProcessQueue()` directly from the constructor. If `ProcessQueue()` worked correctly, the constructor would never return.

Comment: @svick all good points, I dashed this out quickly going mostly from memory, which I guess I should have mentioned in the post.  (And I've been sick for the last two days, which has kept me away from SO...)