# C# async tasks in a queue or waiting list

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, throttling

i have an async Task like this:

```
public async Task DoWork()
{

}
```

And i have at the moment a:

```
List<Task> tmp = new List<Task>();
```

where i add the tasks.

I start the tasks like this:

```
foreach (Task t in tmp)
{
    await t;
}
```

Now my Question:

What`s the best way to start the tasks and only run 3 of them, at the same time (until the others are waiting)?

I think i need something like a queue/waiting list?

It should also be possible to add more tasks after the queue is started.

I`am using .NET 4.5.

Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: Try this post might help you [TPL Queue Processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929592/tpl-queue-processing)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually, the tasks *start* as soon as you call `DoWork`; when you `await` them, you are *finishing* the tasks.

One option for throttling tasks is [`SemaphoreSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which you can use as such:

```
private SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(3);
public async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
  await _mutex.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    ...
  }
  finally
  {
    _mutex.Release();
  }
}
```

Another option is to use an actual queue, like an [`ActionBlock<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which has built-in throttling support.

Comment: Wow, thank you. It works like a charm! I use now: SemaphoreSlim

Comment: You could also consider using Reactive Extensions for throttling.