# UWP app faster image loading?

Tags: c#, image, performance, win-universal-app

I am writing an app for the Universal Windows Platform, where I need to load some images to display in a list. Now my issue is that this loading takes way too long for the user. I currently set the source of the images in the `XAML`, using binding, like so: `{Binding Image}`.

I only have access to the full-resolution images, so I would like to know if there is a way to make these images smaller before placing them on the UI, so only the smaller image needs to remain in memory. Is there a way to configure an `Image` UI element so that it performs this resizing itself?

Also, is there a way to load these images lazily, because now my UI is blocked by the loading of these images.

Edit: The code I am using to load my local images into my `Image` (this is inside of a `ListView.ItemTemplate`):

```
<Image
    Grid.Row="0"
    Source="{Binding Image}"
    Stretch="Uniform"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: Not sure if that will help - but maybe instead of showing whole images, show their thumbnails?

Comment: Where do you get these images from? Locally or online? Is the blocking happen on the ui side, or does it just take very long to load these images. If it's taking very long on the loading of the image, maybe this will help you out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps

Comment: Are you creating BItmapImage or Binding image url?

Comment: @wuerzelchen I am loading local images (downloaded somewhere else, but that part works and happens entirely before my list is populated with URIs to local images), which are pretty big (because I need them high-res somewhere else), but in the list I am only showing small images. I use the same image, which blocks the UI for the duration these large images are loading. I will edit my question

Comment: Please post the code so that we ca understand

Comment: I would suggest resizing the images when you download them. This because if you do the resizing in my converter solution below it will be done over and over.

Comment: @TomDroste It is indeed better to resize them after they have been downloaded, I will do that, thanks!

Comment: @vrwim I would suggest the same. You could use this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929592/tpl-queue-processing with a job queue. So you would bind a collection of thumbnails, which are going to be added as soon as a job has finished the resizing. When you have some nice transitions in your UI it would aswell look pretty neat how the list ist getting filled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lazy load and resize the images by using a converter. In is the start of an converter you can use. With this the lazy loading is done for you. I don't have a resize example ready however.

**Converter code**

```
class LoadAttachmentAsyncConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        Task<BitmapImage> taskToExecute = GetImage(<some parameter>);
        //Possibly handle some other business logic
        return new NotifyTaskCompletion<BitmapImage>(taskToExecute);
    }

    public async Task<BitmapImage> GetImage(object someParameter) {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        //do (async stuff) to fill the image;
        return image;
    }
}
```

**XAML code**

```
<Image Source="{Binding Result}" DataContext="{Binding converterObjValue, Converter={StaticResource ConverterName}}"/>
```

For implementing the resize you can find information here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/490b9c01-db4b-434f-8aff-d5c495e67e55/how-to-crop-an-image-using-bitmaptransform?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: What is the `converterObjValue` in the XAML? And I can put resizing code in the "do async stuff to fill the image", right?

Comment: The converterObjValue is the object that is passed into the converter. I've used this method to pass in the user information so I could retrieve the thumbnail from internet. 

You can indeed put the resizing code in there yes

Comment: That will bind with the DataContext like a normal Binding, right? (I am not very fluent in this binding thing)

Comment: Yes. What it will do is it will bind the datacontext to the task that will be returned. This way the source can be bound to the result of that task (the loaded image)

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and I'll accept if this solved my problem :)

Comment: Oke, let me know if you need more help

Comment: @vrwim if my solution solved your problem, please accept my answer as the solution.

Comment: I ended up not using this, as my issue was only that the images were too big. Once I scaled them down (before the UI needs them), my issue was gone. But this works for what I asked, so correct answer.

Comment: This seems to have worked for my problem of binding to a huge list of images and not having WPF's IsAsync binding modifier. Only thing different is that with the new AsyncEx package, it is `return NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(taskToExecute)`. Can you explain a bit how / why it works? Is there anything more recent that has added async bindings to UWP?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do lazy load in your VM.

```
    // You can also use BitmapImage directly, if you'd like to make reloading faster and don't care memory usage.
    private WeakReference<BitmapImage> image;

    public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get
        {
            BitmapImage image;
            if(this.image != null && this.image.TryGetTarget(out image))
                return image;
            image = new BitmapImage();
            this.image = new WeakReference<BitmapImage>(image);
            var ignore = Task.Run(()=>
            {
                //Load image here.
                //Don't forget to use Dispatcher while calling SetSourceAsync() or setting Source.
            });
            return image;
        }
    }
```